# set select2 option using text not value

Tags: jquery-select2

I know if i have a select2 and i want to set one of the options, i can do run this code.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $('#btn').change(function(){
       $('#select').val(4).trigger("change")
     });    
 });
```

Lets say i want to get the text of the option

```
<option value=4>California</option>
```

but if i want to set it based on the text not the value, how do i do it?

I tried doing

```
$("#select").select2(data.text(), "California");
```

but it didnt work.

How can i do this programatically in jquery or javascript.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 11):

For example: If you need to find Australia among other countries

```
let long_name = 'Australia';
let $element = $('.country-js')
let val = $element.find("option:contains('"+long_name+"')").val()
$element.val(val).trigger('change.select2');
```

Other answers did not work for me, probably because I use newer version of select2

Comment: Saved my life. Spent the last 2 hours banging my head searching for a solution with a select trying everything, then finally dawns on me to search for a `select2` option the first answer BAM! solves it for me. Much thanks!

Comment: @CesarBielich why did not you vote it up, if it worked for you?

Answer (score 3):

In addition for multi selects use this, for not losing already selected values

```
var selected=$("#foo option:selected").map(function(){ return this.value }).get();
selected.push( $("#foo option:contains('text')").val() );
$("#foo").val(selected).trigger('change');
```

Answer (score 2):

Further to Shakeel Ahmed's answer, you should call `.trigger('change')`, so in total something like this:

```
$("#select").select2("val", $("#select option:contains('Text')").val()).trigger('change');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use following codes

```
$("#select").select2("val", $("#select option:contains('Text')").val() );
```

If will select option using your ***Text***

Comment: Use California instead of Text